# Can I push a commit using the gitlab API using push options

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I would like to create a commit using the GitLab API:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions

skipping CI pipelines (`git push -o ci.skip`)

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include push options when creating commits through the API. However, you can the commit message to [skip the pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#skip-a-pipeline) in the same way as `-o ci.skip`.

By default, if the commit message contains `[ci skip]`, the pipeline will be skipped.

Alternatively, you can use `workflow:rules:` to exclude a pipeline on a commit message pattern of your choosing that you control in the `commit_message` parameter. Alternatively still, you may also do so on any other condition, like perhaps the commit author (`$CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR`), which you can control in the `author_email` parameter to the commit API.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /mymessage/'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR == "email+skip-pipeline@example.com"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```